# Package enumitem: Undefined label, with babel French

Tags: babel, enumitem, babel-french

I'm getting the error `Package enumitem: Undefined label` with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{10}
\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{10}

\setlist[itemize]{label=$\cdot$}

\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=--}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=*}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}

\begin{itemize}
    \item {\selectlanguage{english} Test}
    \item Text
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You're misusing `\selectlanguage`. Use `otherlanguage*` or `\foreignlanguage`.

Comment: @egreg What is the difference here? I thought that putting `\selectlanguage` in a group is the same as using `\foreignlanguage`.

Comment: No, it's not the same. In the particular case, it's `babel-french` kicking in, but that's secondary.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I don't quite understand, could you please explain in more detail? Actually I've always been using `\selectlanguage` in group for locally changing the language, and this is the first time I encountered an error. And it only happens when I'm trying to extend the number of levels of `itemize`.

Comment: *Don't* use `\selectlanguage` for *locally* change language. Never. It's just that simple.

Comment: There is an explanation in the `babel` manual. See the first “Warning” in § 1.7, “Basic language selectors”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A language switch can set and reset lots of things. french for example stores and then restore the itemize labels

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\begin{document}


\selectlanguage{french}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}
\begin{itemize} 
    \item Text
    \item Text
\end{itemize}

\selectlanguage{english} 

\begin{itemize}
    \item Text
    \item Text
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Such changes are often (as here) not local but global changes. This means that if you change the language with `\selectlanguage` in the middle of a list you are confusing LaTeX quite heavily. Use `\selectlanguage` with care.

Comment: I fully agree with @Ulrike. Nevertheless, in that precise example, English being the main language, babel-french does not alter the list layout at all, so there is no need to store/restore lists' settings when switching languages…  I'll try to fix this asap.

Comment: @DanielFlipo yes I wondered about that, but even if you fix it: selectlanguage is not a local command.

Comment: @UlrikeFisher of course `\selectlanguage` is not local, but its misuse here reveals something wrong in babel-french which needs to be fixed.